# Bootstrap's grid layout not positioning the image and text side by side. Please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm only a few months old in web development and i know my code is pretty simple but i have tried everthing i know but it is not working. The text and image are not aligning side by side if i increase the width of the image to 100% . also i want the image to go off screen. here is my html code (removing the images since i cant post it).
My css code just contains `width=100%;` and `overflow:hidden;`

```
    <div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-6">

    <h2>BE HEALTHY</h2>
    <p>We are Fitlo, your number one app for weight loss, diet planning and a better overall well being. We’re dedicated to giving you the very best of health and lifestyle from the comfort of your home or office.</p>

 </div>


<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img class="image" src="" alt="bowl of food">
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I will post this as an answer.

1. Just to be sure, you're using `col-lg-6`, so that will put the columns at 50% after large screen and above. If you're looking at a small screen, you'd need either `col-md-6`, or `col-sm-6`, or just `col-6` if you want 2 columns all over.
2. If you already know that, then add the class `img-fluid` to your image. That should work out. This is the Bootstrap class to make images responsive. [Bootstrap Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/#responsive-images)

I tried it on the attached [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d60z157u/1/) link, make sure to expand the display box for the `-lg` breakpoint to take effect.

Comment: Actually I'm using `col-lg-6` so the text and image will align side by side but that is not happening. The image is being pushed below the text on larger devices too.

Comment: Yes, in that case, try the 2nd option! I put up a demo in the fiddle as well.

Comment: It works! My image is being positioned  next to the text but now the `overflow:hidden;` is not working. When i assign the width to 100% scroll bars appear. What should I do?

Comment: Great! For the scrollbars, Bootstrap adds a default padding for all grid columns. You can easily remove them using something called [gutter](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) classes. In your case: add the class `g-0` to your row div (assuming you're using Bootstrap 5). That should remove all the spaces and remove the scrollbars. For Bootstrap 4, you'll have to add a negative margin instead.

Comment: Now this is what I'm getting. https://jsfiddle.net/5c0w6yj3/

Comment: I got the desired result by applying a `.container` class and `g-0`. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad it worked out, please select the answer/comment as the accepted answer if it helped. Thanks!